# Matching (part of a(n)) alphanumeric word enclosed by two asterisks

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex that accomplishes the following:

```
 **Only single**, alphanumeric p**art**s of **words** enclosed by two asterisks should be matched.****
```

From this string, "art" and "words" should be filtered.

So far, I've got `\*{2}(\w+)`, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to deal with the closing asterisks.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - How else would you go about doing this?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of things like `**foo**bar**`?

Comment: @JosephSilber: I don't know. A simple walk-through could probably get the job done minimally. You didn't answer my question, though. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would agree with you, but I already got proven wrong, some languages (especially interpreted ones) are slower when it comes to String operation (done by the language itself) than a simple regex (delegated to another language). In my case, it was a replacement of some characters that was faster with a regex in javascript than a loop over the string. And just if you're interested, have a look at this article: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this `\*{2}([A-Za-z0-9]+)\*{2}`

```
\*     <- An asterisk (escaped as * is already a symbol)
{2}    <- Repeated twice
(      <- Start of a capturing group
  [A-Za-z0-9]    <- An alphanum (careful with \w, it's the equivalent of [a-zA-Z0-9_] not [a-zA-Z0-9])
  +              <- Repeated at least once
)      <- End of the capturing group
\*     <- An asterisk (again)
{2}    <- Repeated twice
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

[`\*{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*{2}`](http://regex101.com/r/eI1bU1)

[image]

Comment: Nice tool!, I'll stick with my manual explanations where I can describe more things if needed, but this is a really neat tool!

Comment: Yeah, it's really cool. Found it [over at reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/15s4sv/finally_released_an_update_to_my_regular/)

Comment: Thank you! I'll be using \w to keep it simple. Noted, though, that \w also includes underscores apparently, and could be considered less pure for that reason.

Comment: Colin: Heh, after a bit of stalking I see you're at Oxford University just like me :p

Comment: Chris: Yeah, you said alphanumeric in the title so I took it to mean not using `\w`.

Comment: True, strictly speaking, this would make for an answer that better suits the description. \w is in line with the regex already provided, however, and causes less confusion so the part that was missing stands out more and the general structure becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=\*\*)[a-z\d]+(?=\*\*)~i', $string, $matches);
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OJHzEs

---

Here's a detailed explanation:

[image]

Comment: While valid, it this regex will also capture every alphanum in this string `**test**test2**test3**` which might not be what you want.